# Laravel 5 - Where to define functions and call them in views & controllers

Tags: php, helper, laravel-5

I have following function and want to call it from view. Basically i want to put all common functions in one file. I am not sure where to create that file and how to call it inside controller and view.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;

class CommonController extends Controller {

public function BytesToMB($bytes=0)
{
    if(empty($bytes))
    return 0;

    $kb = ceil($bytes/1024);

    $mb = ceil($kb/1024);

    return $mb;
}

}
```

So far i have created CommonController.php in app/Http/Controllers and put above function in it.

Then in other controller i have tried to call it following way:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Common;

class SongsController extends Controller {
    public function index($id)
    {
       echo Common::BytesToMB('7012187');
    }
}
```

But i am getting error:

```
 Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Common' not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, new try. You missed to use the complete class name and add the static keyword:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;

class CommonController extends Controller {

    public static function BytesToMB($bytes=0)
    {
        if(empty($bytes))
        return 0;

        $kb = ceil($bytes/1024);

        $mb = ceil($kb/1024);

        return $mb;
    }

}
```

And then:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// You do not need to define this, if you are in the same namespace
use App\Http\Controllers\CommonController;

class SongsController extends Controller {
    public function index($id)
    {
       echo CommonController::BytesToMB('7012187');
    }
}
```

Another and more OOP solution is to use the function from the parent class:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;

class CommonController extends Controller {

    protected function BytesToMB($bytes=0)
    {
        if(empty($bytes))
        return 0;

        $kb = ceil($bytes/1024);

        $mb = ceil($kb/1024);

        return $mb;
    }

}
```

And then:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// You do not need to define this, if you are in the same namespace
use App\Http\Controllers\CommonController;

class SongsController extends CommonController {

    public function index($id)
    {
       echo $this->bytesToMB('7012187');
    }
}
```

Comment: I added public static but not working. I think its second thing because error says class not found. So its not including class properly.

Comment: I edited my answer, because i recognize the missing of the class itself too late :p

Comment: not working, i have also edited question. I tried only Common instead of CommonController but its same.

Comment: Ok thats working now.. Just edit your answer to // You do not need to define this, if you are in the same namespace
use App\Http\Controllers\CommonController;

Comment: Please also tell me how to access this function in view!

Comment: Why would you use another controller to place up functionality ? You are extending another one and you don't need any of it's inheritance.You could simply create a class, weather or not that class is on the app name space add it to psr-4 on composer and either create instances of that class or call it's static methods, you can pass the class instance to a view, or you can register it as a Facade.

Comment: You are completely right. I extended my answer to match this situation too.

Comment: @Burimi I am new to laravel, i dont know best practice. Can u provide steps ?